# MySQL Unknown Column 'City' in 'having' clause

Tags: mysql, sql

The goal writing this set of code is to display a storename and the max and min sale prices for stores that are located in Boulder. The code I have is below. If it helps, I am using MySQL Workbench.

```
Select StoreName, Round(Max(SalesPrice),2), Round(Min(SalesPrice),2) 
FROM Dim_Store INNER JOIN Fact_ProductSales 
ON Dim_Store.StoreID = Fact_ProductSales.StoreID 
GROUP BY StoreName HAVING City = 'Boulder';

-- Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'City' in 'having clause'
```

Comment: You can just put `City = 'Boulder'` in a `WHERE` clause before the `GROUP BY`. The `HAVING` clause is only for things that are aggregated in your grouping. e.g. `HAVING Max(SalesPrice) > 2`

Comment: You have several problems, not just that.  Please show the `CREATE TABLE` statements for `Dim_Store` and `Fact_ProductSales`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select StoreName, Round(Max(SalesPrice),2), Round(Min(SalesPrice),2) 
FROM Dim_Store INNER JOIN Fact_ProductSales 
ON Dim_Store.StoreID = Fact_ProductSales.StoreID
Where City = 'Boulder'
GROUP BY StoreName ;
```

Use the conditional in the Where statement, not in the having statement
The having statement is used to filter on the results of an aggregation

Comment: Genius! Yes it worked. Thank you for the help!